# Problema com função recursiva em array

Tags: php, recursão, array-multidimensional

Eu tenho uma função (que achei aqui no fórum) que faz uma pesquisa no array e retorna se tem o valor que eu procuro ou não, até ai tudo bem. Só que surgiu uma necessidade, eu preciso retornar o numero da posição que ele achou , pois ele retornar apenas -1, ai eu sei que valor não foi achado. Então eu gostaria que ele me retornasse qual a posição do array ele achou o valor. Como ainda não tenho muita experiencia , não consegui editar o código para fazer isso. Segue o código.

```
function search($haystack, $needle, $index = NULL) {

 if (is_null($haystack)) {
    return -1;
  }

$arrayIterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack);

$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayIterator);

while ($iterator->valid()) {

    if (( ( isset($index) and ( $iterator->key() == $index ) ) or ( !isset($index) ) ) and ( $iterator->current() == $needle )) {

        return $arrayIterator->key();
    }

    $iterator->next();
  }

   return -1;
}
```

Utilização

```
$arrayBanco = returnBanco();
echo search($arrayBanco, $cnpj, 'CNPJ');
```

Estrutura do meu array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [CNPJ] => 02814497000700
        [SERIE] => 1
        [NOTA] => 000245924
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CNPJ] => 05651966000617
        [SERIE] => 1
        [NOTA] => 000365158
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CNPJ] => 05651966000617
        [SERIE] => 1
        [NOTA] => 000365645
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [CNPJ] => 05651966000617
        [SERIE] => 1
        [NOTA] => 000365946
    )
```

)

Comment: Editei ali denovo, da uma olhada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poder utilizar a função `array_search` para retornar o valor da chave do array:

```
$key = array_search('conteudo a ser buscado', $array);
```

Segue Referencia do php:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php

Edição:
Nesse caso Multidimensional, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php
function pesquisarCNPJ($array,$CNPJ){
$i=1;
foreach($array as $valores){
    if($valores['CNPJ']==$CNPJ){
    return $i;
    }
$i++;
}
}
if(pesquisarCNPJ($array,"05651966000617")){
echo "CNPJ encontrado na posição".pesquisarCNPJ($array,"05651966000617");
}
else {
echo "Não encontrado";
}


?>
```

Ou até mesmo usando a proprio função do php:

```
echo $key = array_search($CNPJ, array_column($array, 'CNPJ'));
```

E no caso, se existir mais ed um cnpj, é só guardar os indices achados em um novo array, ai voce terá todas as posições que existe o CNPJ

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Parece que essa função não funciona para arrays multidimensionais ..

Comment: como que esta a estrutura do seu array?

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta e colocar o array lá.

Comment: Coloca em vez do return -1, poe `return $iterator->key();` E ve se funciona

Comment: Não funcionou , ele apenas deixa de retornar os arrays cujo os valores não batem com meu parâmetro de busca

Comment: @MarlonCastro pode ter mais de um CNPJ igual?

Comment: Estava no almoço.. Sim pode. EU até pensei em fazer desse jeito que você , mas estou preocupado com a performace

Comment: Quanto a performance, não haverá diferenças, ou pelo menos não diferenças significativas, visto que a sua função tambem usa laço de repetição, se esse é seu medo. Desde que não seja um array com milhares de registro, tudo ok kk

Comment: kkk.. É , eu adptei sua função um pouco para poder me atender aqui. Deu certo , mas ainda estou preocupado com a performance kk. Mas de qualquer maneira, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se funciona para você:

```
function search($haystack, $needle, $index = NULL) {

if (is_null($haystack)) {
  return -1;
}

$arrayIterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack);

$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayIterator);

while ($iterator->valid()) {

if (( ( isset($index) and ( $iterator->key() == $index ) ) or ( !isset($index) ) ) and ( $iterator->current() == $needle )) {

     return array('interator'=>$arrayIterator->key(),'position'=>$index);
   }

   $iterator->next();
 }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ele me retornar o vazio na posiçao.                                                             ```Array
(
    [interator] => 2
    [position] => 
)```

Comment: Embora que analisando bem o seu código o $iterator->key() em si já é a posição que o index está naquele momento

Comment: Então , pensei que assim daria certo , mas ele nao me retorna a posicao que ele achou cada valor. Vou editar minha resposta e colocar lá meu array.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, cria uma variavel chamada $return[] = array('interator'=>$arrayIterator->key(),'position'=>$index);

Comment: Não deu certo..